# How to Generate Tables columns and rows in PHP from 2 arrays

Tags: php

[image]

Apologies to all those who might feel offended or pissed by my question we all learn everyday.
I want to be able to generate a table that will look like what i have in this picture from this two different arrays also shown on the table.

I can generate a normal table with a foreach loop but in this case it becoming confusing and i have not been able to try anything tangible.  So any help will be appreciated .

example raw array

```
$data1 = array(
     '0' => array('time'=> '1.00pm', 'reading' =>'271', 'machine'=>'machine1'),
     '1' => array('time'=> '2.00pm', 'reading' =>'261', 'machine'=>'machine1'),
     '2' => array('time'=> '3.00pm', 'reading' =>'172', 'machine'=>'machine1'),
     '3' => array('time'=> '4.00pm', 'reading' =>'300', 'machine'=>'machine1'),
     '4' => array('time'=> '5.00pm', 'reading' =>'142', 'machine'=>'machine1')
    );
$data2 = array(
     '0' => array('time'=> '1.00pm', 'reading' =>'500', 'machine'=>'machine2'),
     '1' => array('time'=> '2.00pm', 'reading' =>'432', 'machine'=>'machine2'),
     '2' => array('time'=> '3.00pm', 'reading' =>'109', 'machine'=>'machine2'),
     '3' => array('time'=> '4.00pm', 'reading' =>'44', 'machine'=>'machine2'),
     '4' => array('time'=> '5.00pm', 'reading' =>'18', 'machine'=>'machine2')
    );
```

so any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this for the desired result

```
$header = ['machine','1.00pm','2.00pm','3.00pm','4.00pm','5.00pm'];
$html = "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<count($header); $i++){
  $html.= "<th>".$header[$i]."</th>";
}
$html .= "</tr>";
$res = [
    array_merge(
        array_unique(array_column($data1,'machine')),
        array_column($data1, 'reading','time')
    ),
    array_merge(
        array_unique(array_column($data2,'machine')),
        array_column($data2, 'reading','time')
    )
];
foreach($res as $key => $value){
 $html  .= "<tr>";
 foreach($header as $ikey => $ivalue){
    $index = ($ivalue == 'machine') ? 0 : $ivalue;
    $html .= "<td>".$res[$key][$index]."</td>";
 }
 $html  .= "</tr>";
}
$html .= "</table>";
```

**Pattern II.**

```
$header = ['time','machine1','machine2'];
$html = "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<count($header); $i++){
  $html.= "<th>".$header[$i]."</th>";
}
$res = [
  array_merge(
    array_column($data1, 'reading','time')
 ),
 array_merge(
    array_column($data2, 'reading','time')
 )
];
for($i=0;$i<count($res)-1;$i++){
    foreach($res[$i] as $key => $value){
     $html .= '<tr>';
     $html .= '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
     $html .= '<td>'.$res[$i][$key].'</td>';
     $html .= '<td>'.$res[$i+1][$key].'</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';
 }   
} 
echo $html;
```

[image]

Comment: this worked for the first kind of Table can you also help with the second kind in the photo you save my day.

Comment: Please help with the Second table. @rakesh-jakhar

Comment: Please the second table is not working its creating many rows instead please take a look at your Code please @rakesh-jakhar

Comment: @Donsplash checkout the screen shoot

Comment: for($i=0;$i<count($res)-1;$i++){     this was where i had issues when using it with more than 3 column it will do a for loop more than required.  But Thanks it works very well now

Answer (score 0):

Well, this answer contains all the tables

```
<?php
$data1 = array(
 '0' => array('time'=> '1.00pm', 'reading' =>'271', 'machine'=>'machine1'),
 '1' => array('time'=> '2.00pm', 'reading' =>'261', 'machine'=>'machine1'),
 '2' => array('time'=> '3.00pm', 'reading' =>'172', 'machine'=>'machine1'),
 '3' => array('time'=> '4.00pm', 'reading' =>'300', 'machine'=>'machine1'),
 '4' => array('time'=> '5.00pm', 'reading' =>'142', 'machine'=>'machine1')
);
$data2 = array(
 '0' => array('time'=> '1.00pm', 'reading' =>'500', 'machine'=>'machine2'),
 '1' => array('time'=> '2.00pm', 'reading' =>'432', 'machine'=>'machine2'),
 '2' => array('time'=> '3.00pm', 'reading' =>'109', 'machine'=>'machine2'),
 '3' => array('time'=> '4.00pm', 'reading' =>'44', 'machine'=>'machine2'),
 '4' => array('time'=> '5.00pm', 'reading' =>'18', 'machine'=>'machine2')
);

echo $data1[0]['machine'];
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo "<th>Time</th>";
echo "<th>reading</th>";
echo '</tr>';


foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $value['time'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $value['reading'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo '</table>';

echo '<br>';
    echo $data2[0]['machine'];
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<th>Time</th>";
    echo "<th>reading</th>";
    echo '</tr>';


    foreach ($data2 as $key => $value) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $value['time'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $value['reading'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';




    echo '<br>';






    echo '<br>';
            echo '<table>';


            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>machin</th>";
            foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
              echo "<th>" . $value['time'] . "</th>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>machine1</td>";
            foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
              echo "<td>" . $value['reading'] . "</td>";
            }
              echo "</tr>";

              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>machine2</td>";
                foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
              echo "<td>" . $data2[$key]['reading'] . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
            echo '</table>';




            echo '<br>';







            echo '<br>';

                    echo '<table>';
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo "<th>Time</th>";
                    echo "<th>machine1</th>";
                    echo "<th>machine2</th>";
                    echo '</tr>';


                    foreach ($data2 as $key => $value) {
                      echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>" . $value['time'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $data1[$key]['reading'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $value['reading'] . "</td>";
                      echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo '</table>';




                    echo '<br>';



 ?>
```